# WordPress Plugin database error You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I receive this multiple times each time a page loads.
[07-Jul-2018 17:30:49 UTC] WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND p.post_status='publish'' at line 6 for query SELECT count(*) FROM wp_posts p

```
    [07-Jul-2018 17:30:49 UTC] WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND p.post_status='publish'' at line 6 for query SELECT count(*) FROM wp_posts p
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON tr.object_id = p.ID
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id
INNER JOIN wp_geo_mashup_location_relationships gmlr ON gmlr.object_id = p.ID AND gmlr.object_name = 'post'
WHERE tt.term_id =
AND p.post_status='publish' made by require('wp-blog-header.php'),
require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'),
include('/themes/hestia-child/front-page.php'),
get_footer, locate_template, load_template,
require_once('/themes/hestia-child/footer.php'),
do_action('hestia_do_footer_child'),
WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters,
call_user_func_array, hestia_the_footer_content_child,
dynamic_sidebar, call_user_func_array, WP_Widget->display_callback,
WP_Widget_Categories->widget, wp_dropdown_categories,
walk_category_dropdown_tree, call_user_func_array, Walker->walk, Walker->display_element,
call_user_func_array, Walker_CategoryDropdown->start_el, apply_filters('list_cats'),
WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, GeoMashup::list_cats, GeoMashupDB::category_located_post_count
```

I think it leads to a section of GeoMashup's "geo-mashup-db.php" (copied below) and I've read some things about upper/lower case mismatches between ID/id that can cause this, but I can't seem to find any instances of that. Any help or suggestions would be great.

```
* Get the number of located posts in a category.
*
* @since 1.2
*
* @param id $category_id
* @return int
*/
public static function category_located_post_count( $category_id ) {
global $wpdb;

$select_string = "SELECT count(*) FROM {$wpdb->posts} p
INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} tr ON tr.object_id = p.ID
INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} tt ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id
INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}geo_mashup_location_relationships gmlr ON gmlr.object_id = p.ID AND gmlr.object_name = 'post'
WHERE tt.term_id = " . esc_sql( $category_id ) ."
AND p.post_status='publish'";
return $wpdb->get_var( $select_string );
}

/**
* Get categories that contain located objects.
*
* Not sufficient - probably want parent categories.
*
* @return array Located category id, name, slug, description, and parent id
*/
private static function get_located_categories() {
global $wpdb;

$select_string = "SELECT DISTINCT t.term_id, t.name, t.slug, tt.description, tt.parent
FROM {$wpdb->prefix}geo_mashup_location_relationships gmlr
INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} tr ON tr.object_id = gmlr.object_id
INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} tt ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id
INNER JOIN {$wpdb->terms} t ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
WHERE tt.taxonomy='category'
ORDER BY t.slug ASC";
return $wpdb->get_results( $select_string );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An older post, but for what it's worth: the issue is with Geo Mashup's widget option that "automatically" creates a map link for categories (admin > "obscure settings").

ALL posts in ALL categories must have ALL `GeoMeta` saved (`la`t, `lng`, `geo-address`, and saved name) or you'll get this error a lot.

Unchecking `Add map links to category lists` will stop the errors.
The shortcodes & template tags to map a category by name/ID will still work fine.

Hope this can help someone.